# Change in coordinate density for np.meshgrid() in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am plotting a vector field using the numpy function `quiver()` and it works. But I would like to emphasize the cowlick in the following plot:

[image]

I am not sure how to go about it, but increasing the density of arrows in the center could possibly do the trick. To do so, I would like to resort to some option within `np.meshgrid()` that would allow me to get more tightly packed x,y coordinate points in the center. A linear, quadratic or other specification does not seem to be built in. I am not sure if `sparse` can be modified to this end.

The code:

```
lim = 10
int = 0.22 *lim
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-lim, lim, int), np.arange(-lim, lim, int))

u = 3 * np.cos(np.arctan2(y,x)) - np.sqrt(x**2+y**2) * np.sin(np.arctan2(y,x))
v = 3 * np.sin(np.arctan2(y,x)) + np.sqrt(x**2+y**2) * np.cos(np.arctan2(y,x))

color = x**2 + y**2
plt.rcParams["image.cmap"] = "Greys_r"
mult = 1
plt.figure(figsize=(mult*lim, mult*lim))
plt.quiver(x,y,u,v,color, linewidths=.006, lw=.1)
plt.show()
```

---

Closing the loop on this, thanks to the accepted answer I was able to finally strike a balance between the density of the mesh as I learned from to do from @flwr and keeping the "cowlick" structure of the vector field conspicuous (avoiding the radial structure around the origin as much as possible):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.meshgrid` just makes a grid of the vectors you provide.
What you could do is contract this regular grid in the center to have more points in the center (best visible with more points), e.g. like so:

```
# contract in the center
a = 0.5  # how far to contract
b = 0.8  # how strongly to contract
c = 1 - b*np.exp(-((x/lim)**2 + (y/lim)**2)/a**2)
x, y = c*x, c*y
plt.plot(x,y,'.k')
plt.show()
```

Alternatively you can `x,y` cooridnates that are not dependent on a grid at all:

```
x = np.random.randn(500)
y = np.random.randn(500)
plt.plot(x,y,'.k')
plt.show()
```

But I think you'd prefer a slightly more regular patterns you could look into poisson disk sampling with adaptive distances or something like that, but the key point here is that for using `quiver`, you can use ANY set of coordinates, they do not have to be in a regular grid.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct the points whereever you want to calculate your field on and quivers will be happy about it. The code below uses polar coordinates and stretches the radial coordinate non-linearly.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lim = 10
N = 10

theta = np.linspace(0.1, 2*np.pi, N*2)

stretcher_factor = 2

r = np.linspace(0.3, lim**(1/stretcher_factor), N)**stretcher_factor

R, THETA = np.meshgrid(r, theta)
x = R * np.cos(THETA)
y = R * np.sin(THETA)

# x,y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
r = x**2 + y**2

u = 3 * np.cos(THETA) - np.sqrt(r) * np.sin(THETA)
v = 3 * np.sin(THETA) + np.sqrt(r) * np.cos(THETA)

plt.rcParams["image.cmap"] = "Greys_r"
mult = 1
plt.figure(figsize=(mult*lim, mult*lim))
plt.quiver(x,y,u,v,r, linewidths=.006, lw=.1)
```

[image]

Edit: Bug taking meshgrid twice

Comment: Guillem, `np.linspace(0.1, 2*np.pi, N*2)` results in overlapping of the first two rays of arrows around zero. `np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N*2)` does the trick. It is elegant of you to move to polar coordinates, but the clustering of arrows around the center erases the cowlick structure of the field.

Comment: @AntoniParellada Unfortunately, the field you have provided doesn't have a cowlick at the origin. The field becomes radial at the origin so no matter how you plot it you won't get a cowlick. I edited my answer with a simplification that makes this patent. As r->0 the field is u=np.cos(theta), v=np.sin(theta) which points radially. In light of this can you accept one of the answers or provide a field with the structure you want at the origin? Thanks!

Comment: Spot on regarding the spoke wheel field (source) at the origin. The idea is to de-emphasize that part.

Comment: I'm afraid that in that case I'm not sure on how to help here. The structure I think you want to emphasize is not there...

Comment: No. That is not what I said.